# What is the English translation for "Schnüffelstück"?

Tags: translation

What is the English translation for the word Schnüffelstück? The word comes from the film Werner.

Comment: Well i don't even know this word in german, although i'm a native german speaker.

Comment: @mru http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTp5wrX1w64

Comment: Oh boy, there's more Werner on Youtube! [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH1TXfIbyrI&feature=related)  [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjtfmtOa7JY&feature=related) [3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5gkVVywlR0&feature=related) [4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T_HFWmXmpQ&feature=related) this simply is a classic that *needs* watching at least once.

Comment: "Ein *waaaaaaas*??" :-)

Comment: "Automatischer Heizkörperentlüfter" - pictures: http://shop.stadtwerke-muenster.de/10-prozent-rabatt-swm/automatischer-heizkoerperentluefter-1-2-zoll.html

Comment: Is it really practicable to translate such a wordplay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a self venting valve for a radiator, look at this one for example: http://www.armstronginternational.com/air-gas-vents-see-thru-1-avc

Answer (score 7):

My dictionary says **snifter valve** (an alternative name for this is *snifting valve*).

Also check this page, where someone asks "[Was ist ein Schnüffelstück?](http://www.motorradfrage.net/frage/was-ist-ein-schnueffelstueck)".

Answer (score -1):

For it's very unusual construct. First of all, it's a compound noun. "Stück" can be translated in various ways. In this context it's a piece to do something with, namely to sniff (schnüffeln, verb). A sniffing implement. It could be a vulgarism for nose. If it were a snifter valve, an industrial piece of equipment to detect odors or gases, the German word for it would be more like Schnüffelventil rather than Schnüffelstück. But that would be an industry specific term that I have never heard before, and I am German. It needs context.

Comment: Ü und ue sind nicht äquivalent und die IT ist hier nicht aus den 70ern. Ein Blick in die Kommentare hätte Dir den Kontext gezeigt und erklärt, was ein Schnüffelstück ist (YouTube-Link) und eine akzeptierte und aufgewertete Antwort gibt es auch schon. 8 Jahre später dann mit Spekulationen aufzuwarten ist nicht sonderlich sinnvoll. Subjektive Erfahrungen (I have never heard before) interessieren hier auch nicht - das kann man im Chat äußern, den man mit ein wenig Reputation besuchen darf.